# How to call function from a member class?

Tags: c++, design-patterns

How to call function(AddUnit) from a member class(menu)? Or how to organise this code?:

```
class Base
{
    BaseMenu *menu;
    virtual void AddUnit(Unit* unit);
}
```

I writing something like stategy or tactic game. Menu has buttons and I want to add units by clicking on this buttons. How to organise this or How to make different menu for different bases? Maybe out menu from base class ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *could* pass a pointer to the `Base` object to the `Menu` constructor and store it in the `Menu` object. Then you could just do e.g. `baseObject->AddUnit(...)`

I'm not saying this is a good idea though, and I think your design might need a little more work.